# How do I rename presets in Lightroom CC

Tags: lightroom, presets, creative-cloud

I have created a few presets in Lightroom CC and, now, I wish to rename them.
How can I rename User Presets in Lightroom CC?

Please, note the question is specific to Lightroom CC and not Lightroom Classic, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is:

- get not edited image
- apply preset you want to rename
- create new preset with desired name
- delete preset with old name

Next idea is a bit speculative as I don't have this software installed:

- find in the filesystem where are stored these files. they have extension `.XMP`
- open the files with your presets in text editor
- search for structure like:

  ```
   <crs:Name>
    <rdf:Alt>
     <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">The name you search for</rdf:li>
    </rdf:Alt>
   </crs:Name>
  ```
- change the text and save the file.
- start Lightroom CC and eventually you will have your presets renamed

Comment: True, but feels a bit like a workaround - I wonder why such on obvious functionality is not available...

Comment: @smn.tino, I edit my question and add another (possible) way. DO not forget to make a backup of the file you edit.